# Robot Framework IDE Python SendKeys Library

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm developing a set of automated tests in which i must send the following controls:

CTRL+C to copy text from my application
CTRL+V to paste text into a variable inside ride

I have tried:

```
Send Keys  ^C
```

Inside RIDE using the SendKeys library from python.

But i always get the following error:

```
TypeError: argument 1 must be char, not unicode
```

I need to do something like:

```
SendKeys   ^C
${text}=   SendKeys ^V
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you provide more info for this "SendKeys" library - I searched for it both on google, and pypi.org, but didn't find anything. Or, is it the `Send Keys` **keyword** from the SeleniumLibrary?

Comment: Hi, no i really mean sendkeys from python library.~You can find more information on this site: https://pypi.org/project/SendKeys/

Comment: Ok, I personally can't help you with this one - the package is not updated since 2013, its homepage doesn't open, can't see the source nor its api docs.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you know of a way to simulate keystrokes in RIDE?